# How to get a key's name in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, configuration

Usually Vim tutorials on remapping keys will only show how to remap and assume you already know how to call a certain key within Vim, such as the well-known `<esc>` or `<F2>`. But what if I need first to know how my key is called (and even if it *is* available for remapping)?

In my specific case, I'm trying to remap <kbd>KEY_SCROLLLOCK</kbd> to <kbd>esc</kbd>, but I don't know how Vim represents it, nor where I could find a list of all available keys in Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim, see `:help key-notation` (I don't see <kbd>KEY_SCROLLLOCK</kbd> in there
though)